# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, regex

I try to extract words from a text. So I have this text:

```
"[' \n\na)\n\n \n\nFa.The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nrut ard wegetables\n\x0c']"
```

and I have this method:

```
def total_fruit_per_sort():
    number_found = re.findall(total_amount_fruit_regex(), verdi47)
    print(number_found)
    fruit_dict = {}
    for n, f in number_found:
        fruit_dict[f] = fruit_dict.get(f, 0) + int(n)
    return {value: key for key, value in fruit_dict.items()}
```

```
def total_amount_fruit_regex(format_=re.escape):

    return r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*(" + '|'.join(format_(word)
                                             for word in fruit_words) + ')'
```

and the fruit_words:

```
fruit_words = ['Appels', 'Ananas', 'Peen Waspeen',
               'Tomaten Cherry', 'Sinaasappels',
               'Watermeloenen', 'Rettich', 'Peren', 'Peen', 'Mandarijnen', 'Meloenen', 'Grapefruit']
```

and then the print returns this:

```
[('16', 'Watermeloenen'), ('360', 'Watermeloenen'), ('6', 'Watermeloenen'), ('75', 'Watermeloenen'), ('9', 'Watermeloenen'), ('688', 'Appels'), ('22', 'Sinaasappels'), ('80', 'Sinaasappels'), ('160', 'Sinaasappels'), ('320', 'Sinaasappels'), ('160', 'Sinaasappels'), ('61', 'Sinaasappels')]
```

So this is correct.

But then I have this text:

```
"['a= (>)\n\nFa\n \n\x0c']"
```

and it returns this:

```
[('566', 'Ananas'), ('706', 'Appels'), ('598', 'Peen Waspeen'), ('176', 'Sinaasappels'), ('179', 'Peen Waspeen'), ('222', 'Peen Waspeen'), ('270', 'Peen Waspeen'), ('400', 'Rettich'), ('129', 'Rettich'), ('48', 'Rettich'), ('', 'Rettich'), ('', 'Rettich'), ('', 'Rettich'), ('160', 'Sinaasappels'), ('6', 'Sinaasappels'), ('320', 'Sinaasappels')]
```

So Rettich has a lot of empty values.

Question. How can I improve this? So that by also the second text all the values will be extracted?

Comment: Some of the `Rettich` have `=` after the number, like `104 = Rettich Klein`. The regexp doesn't match the `=`. You get empty `n` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the regexp to allow an optional `=` or `~=` between the number and fruit.

```
def total_amount_fruit_regex(format_=re.escape):
    return r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*(?:=|~=)?\s*(" + '|'.join(
        format_(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'
```

Comment: #Barmar  Ah, thank you. But still one value is empty: ('', 'Rettich')

Comment: One of the `Rettich` has `~=` before it. I updated the function to allow that.

Comment: But is there not a way that before the searched text if the first occurence is a number that the number has to be selected. Because if you \n322 .= fruitname, or \n322 += fruitname

Comment: The regexp needs to specify what characters are allowed or disallowed there. Is it anything but a newline?

Comment: yes, so any characters has to be omitted

Comment: Just use `.*?` to skip any characters until it matches one of the fruit words.